# Resolving IP address of remote computer from MAC address

Tags: networking, rust

Does anyone know how to resolve the IP address of a LAN computer having only it's MAC address via the rust language?

Comment: Regardless of Rust, is this even possible? Do you have some concrete protocol in mind, or is this both a question about Rust and networking? (I could see doing a v4+v6 broadcast ping on all interfaces and then see if the sought mac address is among the answers. Seems to be possible with the pnet crate. But it will be a bit of a hack.)

Comment: @Caesar. You're right, I really don't know if this is possible. I'm stuck. Already using the pnet library. One way I thought of would be to issue an "show ip arp" command to a cisco switch and then parse the output, but that seems overkill. Didn't try to send a broadcast with the mac address. Will try it and post the result.

Comment: I meant to send a broadcast with a broadcast address and then examine all the responses. But eh, depending on the target OS, ICMP Ping + IP broadcast + MAC unicast may work. I'm curious to hear back about that.

Comment: @Caesar. Tried for IP 255.255.255.255. Doesn't work. Also tried the IP address of the default gateway. Also doesn't work. As for your second suggestion, I don't have the IP address of the target, so I can't ping it.

Comment: I'm surprised, someone in 2010 ask about Rust. Anyway, this tools seems legit able to get IP address using MAC: https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan

Comment: @Abdillah. Very strange. Wrote this question last month (April 2023), not in 2010. Something went wrong with Stackoverflow. Anyhow, thanks for the info. Will look into it.